# More specific self in function declaration

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Given this code:

```
pub fn handle_events(&mut self) {
    use self::glium::glutin::Event;
    for ev in self.display.poll_events() {
        match ev {
            Event::Closed => self.state = GameState::Exiting,
            Event::KeyboardInput(state, _, Some(key))
                if self.input.keys_pressed.contains_key(&key) =>
                    self.handle_keyboard(state, key),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}

fn handle_keyboard(&mut self, state: ElementState, key: VirtualKeyCode) {
    ...
}
```

Rust complains in `self.handle_keyboard(state, key)` that I cannot borrow a mutable reference of `self`, since I already made an immutable borrow of `self.display` in the line `for ev in self.display.poll_events() {`.

In the case that I want to modify just a field in `self` which is not in `self.display`,  is it possible to specify that to the compiler? It would be something like this:

```
fn handle_keyboard(&mut self.field, ...)
```

Comment: you might be interested in https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s not possible to do that. See if you can rearrange things in some other manner, like taking the specific fields that you need by mutable reference instead of all of `self`. If it’s a private method, the ergonomic regression doesn’t matter so much, either.